# Create hashid based on mongodb '_id` attribute

Tags: node.js, hash, mongoose

I have my mongo db schema as follows:

```
var MyTable = mongoose.model('items', {
    name: String,
    keyId: String
});
```

I would like to store keyId as a hashid of '_id' for the item being created.
Eg.
Say, i add an item to db "Hello world", and mongodb would create some '_id' for the item while inserting.

I would like to make use of the `_id` so that i could use that and generate a hashid for the same item being inserted. Something like this:

```
var Hashids = require("hashids"),
    hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt");

var id = hashids.encrypt("507f191e810c19729de860ea");
```

Is there a way, I could know the id before hand. Or I could let mongodb generate value for my `id` field based on criteria I specify.

Comment: You didn't provide an override for the default `_id` type in your model.

Comment: @NeilLunn i am not aware of how to do that

Comment: Well you define it in your schema of course. Presumably: `new Schema({ "_id": String, "someOtherField": String }`. Beware, that `id` is a facsimile of `_id` in most Mongoose operations, so proclaiming a field in your schema definition to the contrary is likely to cause problems.

Comment: Okay. I can rename the `id` field. How about overriding `_id` or generating hashid based on the same.

Comment: Point is "there is a contflict" Call it something else.

Comment: I have renamed `id` to `keyId`.

Comment: So the effect on your overall code is what? You have taken one step from good advice, but your full code does not reflect the affected change. Trying to get to the source of the problem here by suggesting you make necessary changes to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pre save [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to perform operations on the object instance before it gets saved.

```
var MyTableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    keyId: String
});

var Hashids = require("hashids");
MyTableSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.keyId)
        this.keyId = new Hashids("this is my salt").encrypt("507f191e810c19729de860ea");
    next();
});

var MyTable = mongoose.model('items', MyTableSchema);
```

Comment: how do i get '507f191e810c19729de860ea' key here?

Comment: I'm not sure since I took that part of the code as is from your question, but I'm guessing that's the document `id`? if so then `this.id` will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on this. The Hashids module has an EncryptHex (or EncodeHex in v1.x), that is intended for use with mongodb ids.